# bnlearn + Rgraphviz: double arrows instead of undirected edges when customizing plots

Tags: r, bayesian-networks, bnlearn, r-graphviz

I am trying to customize a plot of a graph learned with `bnlearn` using `RGraphviz`. When I have undirected edges, `RGraphviz` turns them into directed edges to both directions when I try to customize the appearance of the graph.

A reproducible example could be:

```
set.seed(1)
x1 = rnorm(50, 0, 1)
x2 = rnorm(50, 0, 1)
x3 = x2 + rnorm(50, 0, 1)
x4 = -2*x1 + x3 + rnorm(50, 0, 1)
graph = data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4)

library(bnlearn)
library(Rgraphviz)

res = gs(graph)
options(repr.plot.width=3, repr.plot.height=3)
g1 <- graphviz.plot(res)
```

Graph not customized:

[image]

So far so good. But if I try to customize it:

```
plot(g1, attrs = list(node = list(fontsize=4, fillcolor = "lightgreen")))
```

Customized graph

[image]

The undirected edge is transformed.

I get this problem even if I just use plot(g1). The issue is that this (saving g1 and then using plot) seems to change the appearance of the graphs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change some of the attributes using the `highlight` argument of `graphviz.plot`, however, it doesn't seem to allow the label size to be altered. You could set this globally, but there is a loss of control doing it this way.

```
par(cex=0.05)
graphviz.plot(res, highlight = 
                list(nodes=nodes(res), fill="lightgreen", col="black"))
```

As shown in your question, you can get a bit more control, using the `attrs` argument for the plot method for the graphNEL object, but again there is the problem of direction.

```
g <- bnlearn::as.graphNEL(res) # use this to avoid printing of graphviz.plot
plot(g,  attrs=list(node = list(fillcolor = "lightgreen", fontsize=4)))
```

Also try to set the graph plot parameters globally using `graph.par`, however, when I try this, the fontsize changes but the colours don't render

```
graph.par(list(nodes=list(fill="lightgreen", fontsize=10)))
renderGraph( Rgraphviz::layoutGraph(bnlearn::as.graphNEL(res)))
```

---

So you can alter the nodes returned by `graphviz.plot` using the function `nodeRenderInfo`:

```
g1 <- graphviz.plot(res)
graph::nodeRenderInfo(g1) <- list(fill="lightgreen", fontsize=8)
Rgraphviz::renderGraph(g1)
```

This does however, plot the network when assigning `graphviz.plot`. So as an alternative you can change the `graphNEL` object (returned by `graphviz.plot`). By default, a `graphNEL` object is either all directed or all undirected, however you can tweak the edges manually. This is what `graphviz.plot` does. By looking at the code of `bnlearn:::graphviz.backend`, it identifies undirected edges, and the renders them using `graph::edgeRenderInfo(graph.plot)`. You can use similar methods to do what you want - use the function `nodeRenderInfo` to update node attributes.

So all together:

```
# this sets all edges to directed
g <- Rgraphviz::layoutGraph(bnlearn::as.graphNEL(res))

# set undirected edges
u <- names(which(graph::edgeRenderInfo(g)[["direction"]] == "both"))
graph::edgeRenderInfo(g)[["arrowhead"]][u] = "none"
graph::edgeRenderInfo(g)[["arrowtail"]][u] = "none"

# update node attributes: fill colour and label fontsize
graph::nodeRenderInfo(g) <- list(fill="lightgreen", fontsize=8)

# render
Rgraphviz::renderGraph(g)
```

Comment: Thanks! In case anyone who sees this is trying to change the shape as well (as I was), just change add to the code:

    shape = rep("ellipse", length(nodes(res)))
    g <- Rgraphviz::layoutGraph(bnlearn::as.graphNEL(res), nodeAttrs = list(shape = shape))